# How can we Send Email using Postman with Amazon Aws Api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to send an email using Aws SES but with the help of postman using API so that i can easily integrate to my java project using okHttp but i cant find any way how to send it using postman they ask me to download sdk/maven dependency which i dont want to do i wanted to do just my API method. Can you please refer me docs as i am really new in aws.

I tried using maven dependency in java which work fine with this dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

But i wanted an API method for this.

Comment: Your question is confusing and not clear.  You state you want to integrate functionality into your Java project.  What do you want to integrate?  DO you want your Java project to be able to send email using SES?

Comment: yes but without maven dependency

Comment: Loading the AWS SDK for Java V2 without using Maven to download the required JARs not an easy task. Why do you not want to use Maven load the required JARs into your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Postman to send an email using AWS SES API without downloading any SDK or Maven dependency.

Here is how you send an email with AWS SES API:

```
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Target: SimpleEmailService.SendEmail


{
    "Destination": {
        "ToAddresses": [
            "recipient@example.com"
        ]
    },
    "Message": {
        "Body": {
            "Text": {
                "Charset": "UTF-8",
                "Data": "This is the message body in text format."
            }
        },
        "Subject": {
            "Charset": "UTF-8",
            "Data": "Test email"
        }
    },
    "Source": "sender@example.com"
}
```

The use the code above you will have to do the following:

- Open Postman and create a new request.
- Set the request method to POST.
- Set the request URL to https://email.{REGION}.amazonaws.com and replace {REGION} with the region code for the AWS region you want to use (e.g. us-west-2).

NB: You will need to authenticate your request by providing AWS access key and secret key as headers: Authorization: AWS {ACCESS_KEY}:{SIGNATURE}. Do not expose your AWS credentials in the Postman. Instead, integrate AWS SDK or set up AWS CLI on your machine to manage your credentials securely.

Comment: when i send the request it says <UnknownOperationException/>

Comment: You will need to gather more information about the error that occurred. Check the following:

Comment: (1) You can Check the server logs on the server-side to see if there are any error messages.

(2) Use Postman to test the request outside of your application and verify that your request works as expected. With that you can Verify your request data.

(3) Check that your server is properly configured and has the necessary resources (disk space, memory, bandwidth) to handle your request.

(4) Contact your server administrator for assistance. They can help you with the issue or provide you with more information about the error.

Comment: how can i see logs for the aws SES?

Comment: To see logs for the aws SES : (1) Open the AWS Management Console and navigate to the CloudWatch service. (2) In the CloudWatch dashboard, click on "Logs" in the left navigation pane. (3) Click on the "Log groups" tab to see a list of all the log groups in your account. (4) Search for the log group associated with your SES emails. The log group should be named "/aws/ses". (5) Click on the log group to see the log streams associated with it. (6) Click on a log stream to see the log events.

Comment: It says there is not log groups even thought i had SES setup and email is going via x-www-form-urlencoded in the Postman sucessfully

Comment: If you are not seeing log groups for SES in CloudWatch Logs, it is possible logging is not enabled for your SES account. You have to Enable it. If you need further help let me know. I will be glad to help.